# remove \n and slash \ from converted json string

Tags: ios, json, swift, string

With the following line i am converting a dict to json string:

```
 let dummyCom = ["companyId" : company.getCompanyId()?.stringValue]

    var error : NSError?

    let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dummyCom, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

    var jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) // the data will be converted to the string
```

I am getting the below description:
Printing description of jsonString:

```
▿ Optional<String>
  - some : "{\n  \"companyId\" : \"1\"\n}"
```

My question is how can i remove \n and \ from string.

I have tried this:
 jsonString = jsonString!.removingPercentEncoding
but getting same result.
Any help or suggetion would be helpfull

Comment: That is just an artifact of the debugger output. Your `jsonString` is fine as it is – just try `print(jsonString)` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace `JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted` with `[]`

And you will get:

```
"{"companyId":1}"
```

And your code will look like:

```
let dummyCom = ["companyId" : 1]

var error : NSError?

let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dummyCom, options: [])

var jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Comment: check my output. there is no "\"

Comment: `description` is very misleading in this context. Don't use it to determine what characters are in the string.

Comment: There is still backslash and slashes. Will be removed with the new option introduced in beta

Answer (score 3):

From iOS13, you can use [withoutEscapingSlashes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/writingoptions/3081260-withoutescapingslashes)

> Specifies that the output doesn’t prefix slash characters with escape characters.

```swift
let data = try jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
let newData = try JSONSerialization.data(
    withJSONObject: json,
    options: [.prettyPrinted, .withoutEscapingSlashes]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the result of using `JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted`. Don't use this option if you don't want the newlines.

The backslashes you see are an artifact of the debugger output, don't worry about those.

Comment: then which option i can use?

Comment: You don't need to use any. Just pass `[]` as the parameter value.

Comment: @Gereon is right. xCode add backslashes and new line characters. You ignore it. If you want to check your jsons is valid or not. Copy paste some text editor app(sublime text) and replace these characters with empty characters.

Comment: @Gereon Since Swift 3 you can omit the parameter, *no options* is the default.

Comment: I am passing this to a c++ function the c++ calling  the API but i am not getting responce due to this invalid json.

Comment: If the C++ code treats this as invalid JSON, it should go read the JSON spec again - this is perfectly valid, with or without the `.prettyPrinted` option.

Comment: Even with no options there is still some backslashes

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer is an excellent workaround, it does not solve the root cause:

The "\n" etc are **not** cause by `JSONSerialization`. The escapes are **created** by printing an optional string:

```
print(jsonString)
```

The solution is much simpler: Do

```
if let jsonString = jsonString {
    print(jsonString)
}
```

Now you can keep your `options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted` and you have a nicely formatted JSON on your console.