# Json String Remove Backslash in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

```
[{\"item_gender\":\"Female\",\"item_type\":\"\",\"item_quantity\":\"1\",\"item_id\":\"21507\"}]
```

How to remove backslash \ from JSON string in swift 4

Comment: Here \ is removed when I submit If any one have any solution on it please help me on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove \n and slash \ from converted json string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221436/remove-n-and-slash-from-converted-json-string)

Comment: The backslashes are virtual to be able to display double quotes in a string literal, they don’t exist in reality.

Answer (score -2):

Please try below code to achieve your goal:
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("[{"item_gender":"Female","item_type":"","item_quantity":"1","item_id":"21507"}]")).toString()

Comment: I am not aware of JSON.parse, JSON.stringify, or toString methods in *Swift.* Can you tell us where those methods are defined?

Comment: find this link may be useful to you 
 (https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/json-parsing-decoding/)